# Why does my INSERT statement not work? (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to insert the values for a device into my SQL Server database with C# ASP.NET Core 6.0.

My code:

```
        public async Task<Int32> AddDevice(int ClientId, int TicketId, string devicename, string deviceversion, string brand, string osVersion, string serialNumber)
        {
            Device newDevice = new Device
            {
                DeviceName = devicename,
                DeviceVersion = deviceversion,
                Brand = brand,
                OsVersion = osVersion,
                SerialNumber = serialNumber
            };
            var testString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=TicketSystem;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(testString))
            {

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Devices (deviceName, deviceVersion, brand, osVersion, serialNumber) VALUES (@ClientId, @TicketId, @DeviceName, @DeviceVersion, @SerialNumber)", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientId", newDevice.ClientId ?? Convert.DBNull);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TicketId", newDevice.TicketId ?? Convert.DBNull);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceName", newDevice.DeviceName);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceVersion", newDevice.DeviceVersion);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", newDevice.Brand);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OsVersion", newDevice.OsVersion);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNumber", newDevice.SerialNumber);
                    await connection.OpenAsync();
                    deviceResult = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
            }
            return deviceResult;
        }
```

I do not get any error, but the data is not being added to the database. However, when adding a breakpoint I can see the following errors:

> Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
>
> StackTrace
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenTdsConnection()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.get_ServerVersion()

Database schema:

[image]

Comment: `I do not get any error` ... `However, when adding a breakpoint I can see the following errors`.  I'd argue you do get an error

Comment: You don't seem to be providing your database user ID and password anywhere.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @fnostro he is passing in the connection to the command constructor

Comment: saw that - i really should scroll right before commenting :) `Deleted`

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is that you are closing the connection before the async command can execute.  also if you are using `using` you don't need to close the connection

Comment: Aside - FYI don't use `nvarchar(max)` unless you really need to be storing more than 4k chars- that must be a seriously large serial number....

Comment: @fnostro i agree.  It all looks okay assuming the connection string is valid.  I'm wondering if maybe you are not awaiting the call into this method.

Comment: Can you turn it into an MCVE and post it on github? I'd like to run it on my local machine

Comment: [This may help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming)

Comment: Have you tried `await`ing the connection, something like `await connection.OpenAsync();` Also try moving the opening the connection inside your `using` statement...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions: I've updated the code in my post. I'm retrieving the same error in my breakpoint as before.

Comment: @Jonesopolis It wouldn't necessarily be an error if OP put the breakpoint outside the connection's using statement and then tried to view some property that depends on an open connection.

Comment: [This answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23140651/1048425). In summary, if your connection attempt fails, the exception is propagated via the returned task, and not thrown. So you may need to check the returned task for an exception rather than relying on `await connection.OpenAsync()` throwing it.

Comment: @GarethD I would argue the answer you linked to is bogus, the person writing that does not understand the documentation. It is perfectly reasonable to await this. There is nothing special about OpenAsync in that regard, exceptions can be caught naturally, unlike when using async void or making an async call without await.

Comment: Is that your actual connection string, are you definitely not using `AttachDbFilename` in the connection string?

Comment: Voting to leave closed as there are too many issues with this code, even after OP is resolved it will be a bad reference to new developers. This is similar to asking multiple questions in the same post, the problems and the solutions are too vague.  @Elbphilharmonie please use some standard exception handling, fix your INSERT statement terms, initialize your parameters correctly (you can't use AddWithValue to pass through optional DbNull) and there is zero value in using the `newDevice` staging object at all.